# Difference between git reset and git checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

What is the difference in the actual effect of the following two commands?
Don't they both make the staging area and the working directory to match the latest commit?

`git reset --hard`

`git checkout <sha-of-latest-commit>`

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? That other question is very broad, but this one is very specific and should get a specific answer.

Comment: Second command will put you in detached HEAD state.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --hard` discards all changes to files in worktree.

`git checkout <sha-of-latest-commit>` preserves those changes.

There is another difference in case when your HEAD references a branch (NOT a detached HEAD mode).

`git checkout <sha-of-latest-commit>` will detach HEAD.

`git reset --hard` will not detach HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` is equivalent to `git reset --hard HEAD`, i.e. it makes your branch point to HEAD (i.e. a NOP) and also resets both the index and the working tree to the same content.

`git checkout` with a literal sha1 will enter detached-head-mode, i.e. you will be no longer on your branch. It also does not change working tree or index.

See for yourself:

```
$ git init
$ touch a b
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 1
$ echo 1 >a; echo 1 >b; git add a #do some changes
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   a

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   b

$ git reset --hard 
$ git status # still on master, changes are gone
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ echo 1 >a; echo 1 >b; git add a  #redo changes
$ git checkout HEAD@{0}
$ git status  #no longer on master, changes are still there
HEAD detached at be924ba
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   a

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   b
```

Comment: *It also does not change working tree or index.* Not true.

Comment: Could you explain, please? I gave a detailed example above showing no change on index and working tree. (Unless you specify an explicit path.)